# .gitignore is not ignoring the files

Tags: git, gitignore

This was the first time I used .gitignore. But it just doesn't work. The file I have entered the name of in the .gitignore file is not getting ignored. You can see that in the 'git status' result and the 'U' near the name of the file in the screenshot below, meaning the file is new and hasn't been added even once yet.

The .gitignore file is the one currently opened, it just has only one file name in it.

[Image includes terminal and the .gitignore file in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwB3x.png)

This is what I get after running the git status

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\thisi\CodeItAll\AutomateWithPy> git status
On branch testing
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        checking.py

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Here's my .gitignore file. Just copy pasted it.

```
checking.py
```

I saw symbols while searching for the solution, but the symbols had different uses, and I have entered the literal file name so the symbols are not needed.

The .gitignore file is commited with the name in it. If it was not, I would have seen it in the 'git status' result. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Note: There does seem to be a space after the `checking.py` in the `.gitignore` file but I can't remove it. When I copy the entire file, I can see a bit of space. But when I go to the end of first line, and press `delete`, it just removes the line two which would have happened normally when there wasn't any character after the line.

P.S.: The answer is found. At least the one that was needed for me. The `.gitignore` file being in UTF-16 encoding was the problem. You can check the answer below.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a space before the file name in .gitignore?

Comment: @choroba Yes I checked again. There aren't any.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Check that `.gitignore` is text in ASCII or UTF-8 encoding, not UTF-16 or -32.

Comment: It was UTF-16. But when I turned it into UTF-8 and saved it, the notepad kept the text it was, but it changed to Chinese in VS Code. It does ignore checking.py now. But not if I erase the Chinese text and add the checking.py. I check again, it's back to UTF-16. To fix it, I deleted the `.gitignore`, removed and committed. Added the file from Notepad because it gives me the option to select the encoding and saved it. It works now. I have added and committed this `.gitignore` and it works. I'll add this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of @phd's comment on the question.

The file is UTF-16 encoded. It should be UTF-8. I tried converting the encoding from the Notepad app and saving it, but the text would change to Chinese in the VS code. And turning it back to `checking.py` text and saving it would convert the file back to UTF-16.

So I removed the file, both directly and from git. Went to Notepad, created a new file, wrote the text I wanted to, and saved it in the project directly. I used the Notepad app because it gives me the option to change the encoding, I selected UTF-8 and saved it. Added the new `.gitignore` to the git tracking, committed the change and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have no spaces before and after filename in the .gitignore file.
Make sure you add `<NEWLINE>` after the line. (Extra empty line does not hurt.)

Check that your real file name is really `checking.py` without special characters.

Did you save the file? In the correct directory? `ls -la` or `ls -l .gitgnore checking.py` might check that. On windows, type manually `dir .gitignore` and `dir checking.py` and check that you see both files listed. Explore `.gitgnore` for strange characters using some sort of hexdump, like `od -c .gitignore`.

Do not use symlink for `.gitignore`, it is not accepted (A recent change?)

UPDATE: It [turned out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76934962/22357050) that the file `.gitignore` was saved in the UTF-16 encoding (see the other answer), which was not recognized by git. Some sort of hexdump utility, or `od -c .gitignore` makes this visible showing that ever other character is zero.

(I would also worry about UTF8 -- that *sometimes* might prepend few chars header which might again not be recognized by git. But you may have luck with UTF8.)

Comment: Always test by `git status` since the `U` letter can have a delay.

Comment: Are those Linux commands? I am on a Windows system. Are there any equivalent commands that I could use? And yes, there aren't any spaces before or after the file name. And in the screenshot, you can see that there's an empty line after the file name already.

Comment: And yes, the git status is shown right there, you can see it in the attached image.

Comment: `ls` is `dir`. For the other one, use any `hexdump` you have. Just checking for spaces. Also the filename potentialy contains space. Could you try to put `*eck*` in `.gitingore` and reissue `git status` ?

Comment: I added the `*eck*` in `.gitignore` but nothing new shows up. The `git status` has the same result shown in the attached image in the post.

Comment: Do you use standard git configurantion? What `venv` means, is it still physical directory? What does `dir .gitignore checking.py` say --- type the charactes manually, still checking for strange characters.

Comment: I just learned git, so no I don't understand the configs. the `venv` is a virtual environment for separating the project from the rest of the PC, basically to avoid conflicts between modules installed in the project and the rest of the PC. I tried `dir .gitignore checking.py`, the result is [here](https://imgur.com/a/PcJ0Xoe).

Comment: Your `dir .gitignore checking.py` did list `.gitignore` but it did not list `checking.py` ! --- I think your filename contains some invisible character. Strictly saying, `dir` says that `checking.py` does not exists. `git status` probably really complains about some file like `che<UCHAR1234>cking.py`  of `checking.py<NEWLINE>` or ... ?

Comment: That's not it. You are forgetting that the command I entered wasn't `dir` it was `dir .gitignore checking.py`. The result of just running the `dir` command is [here](https://imgur.com/a/MUmDH8M). It does include checking.py.

Comment: No. If `dir checking.py` does not show `checking.py` but `dir` shows it, we can almost be sure that there are some invisible characters in `checking.py`. @minorChaos is correct.

Comment: If you're talking about `dir .gitignore checking.py`, well, I ran the command `dir checking.py` and it shows checking.py. But when I run `dir checking.py .gitignore`, it does not show `.gitignore` and only shows `checking.py`. I don't know how that command works but it seems to show only the first file name and not the other.

Comment: Also, read the note I added in the bottom of the question post. It's about spaces after the filename.

Comment: In that case, retype the whole `.gitignore` file manually from scratch. Make sure there are no extra spaces this time. Or it is possible that you've run into the  issue of endline characters. Make sure you use the correct line ending. There are plenty of questions on SO about line endings in git.

Comment: I sugest also to start with a new file. Type `echo  hello > hello` and `echo hello >> .gitignore`  (note double `>>` which appends to the file). What is the the output of `git status` ? (And how does it compare with our problem with  checking.py?).

Comment: Seems like the problem was with the encoding of the file. I made it using `echo checking.py > .gitignore`. It was UTF-16. Turning it into UTF-8 was not working so I created a new UTF-8 file from Notepad and added it to the project dir. I added the answer myself. Thanks for the time you spent helping me.

Comment: @ThisIsSidam do not be said about downvoting, It happens to most of the questions. Many get closed before one manages to give an answer.